# Two drupal installs in nginx

Tags: php, drupal, nginx, drupal-7

Im trying to have 2 websites set up on a CENTOS 7, Digital Ocean server.

One site is to be served from `/srv/http/eventadvisor.in/public_html` and the other from `/srv/http/eventadvisor.in/public_html`.

I installed drupal seccessfully in the first directory. Now when I repeat the steps in the second, it automatically takes the settings from the first site's settings.php and gives the following error:

```
Drupal Already Installed
To start over, you must empty your existing database.
To install to a different database, edit the appropriate settings.php file in the sites folder.
To upgrade an existing installation, proceed to the update script.
View your existing site.
```

I am running a nginx server with the following conf file:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

And each sites configuration file is:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name sanjayshitole.com www.sanjayshitole.com *.sanjayshitole.com;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

#    location / {
        root   /srv/http/sanjayshitole.com/public_html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
#    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /srv/http/eventadvisor.in/public_html;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by using a modification of the configuration shown in this blog: [Lelutin](https://lelutin.ca/posts/Drupal_7_and_Nginx_1.0.4_on_Debian_Squeeze/)

This is my configuration file that worked well (slight centOS specific modifications were made):

```
server {
    server_name sanjayshitole.com;
    root /srv/http/sanjayshitole.com/public_html;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/sanjayshitole.comaccess.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/sanjayshitole.org.error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    # For drush
    location = /backup {
            deny all;
    }

    # Prevent user from accessing settings.php directly
    location ~ ^/sites/[^/]+/settings.php$ {
            deny all;
    }

    ## Replicate the Apache <FilesMatch> directive of Drupal standard
    ## .htaccess. Disable access to any code files. Return a 404 to curtail
    ## information disclosure. Hide also the text files.
    location ~* ^(?:.+\.(?:htaccess|make|txt|log|engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(?:\.php)?|xtmpl)|code-style\.pl|/Entries.*|/Repository|/Root|/Tag|/Template)$ {
            return 404;
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
            return 403;
    }

    location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
            # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
            # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
            #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1&$args;
            rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }

    # Use an SSH tunnel to access those pages. They shouldn't be visible to
    # external peeping eyes.
    location = /install.php {
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
    }

    location = /update.php {
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
    }

 location ~ \.php$ {
            root /srv/http/sanjayshitole.com/public_html;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    }


    ## Drupal 7 generated image handling, i.e., imagecache in core. See:
    ## https://drupal.org/node/371374
    location ~* /sites/.*/files/styles/ {
            access_log off;
            expires 30d;
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    # Fighting with ImageCache? This little gem is amazing.
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ {
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

I would still like an explanation of why the default conf that ships with nginx did not work, so please feel free to answer this question.

SD